# K Theory: Book Recommendations

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, projective-module, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Good people!

So I've been hoping to get into *K* Theory for a while now, and the book that I have been trying to use (and failing) has been Charles Weibel's book by that very title.

The book itself isn't bad, but it's not for the faint-hearted, and can appear quite dense and challenging to a relative newbie like me. As such, I was wondering if someone might be able to recommend a book or two or three or $n$ to help "ease" my way into Weibel. Something that touches upon the constructions he introduces in the first chapter--Picard groups, topological and algebraic vector bundles, Chern classes, etc.--but being more, well, *easy* for a newbie to process.

I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: If stuck on trying to understand things conceptually in algebraic K theory, skimming this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3787 can provide some motivation.

Comment: I guess this question is quite old at this point, but for any future visitors, I highly recommend Milnor's classic "Introduction to Algebraic K-Theory". Like all Milnor books, the writing is of the highest quality, and the material is a great primer for some of the more sophisticated parts of Weibel's book.

Answer (score 7):

From just as much of a newbie, I'd recommend you [these notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506142840/https://users.ictp.it/%7Epub_off/lectures/lns023/Friedlander/Friedlander.pdf) by Eric Friedlander to begin with.

I'm personally also fond of [this introductive article](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201907/rnoti-p1034.pdf) by Inna Zakharevich.

Coming to... larger books, I'm not really aware of any "easier" reference than Weibel's, so I think I'll leave recommendations to users way more expert than me on the subject.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I like:
An Algebraic Introduction to K-Theory , Bruce A. Magurn

https://www.cambridge.org/an/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/algebraic-introduction-k-theory?format=HB&isbn=9780521800785

THis is suitable for beginners, with lot of interesting sources of $K_0$ and $K_1$, and classical theorems (such as excision exact sequences)

Answer (score 1):

Other than the above recommendations, I would also recommend [this paper by Grayson](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Edan/Papers/qs-published-final.pdf), which gives a big picture overview of Quillen's $K$-theory.

If and when you can understand Grayson's papers above, I would highly recommend Quillen's original paper [Higher algebraic K-theory I](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0067053). While it is certainly not for beginners, I think it still is something which is quite readable with the correct background.